# Why do my links require two taps on iOS when using AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense, ux

A weird issue appears when I'm integrating AdSense on my pages. My standard links (simple `<a>` elements) need to have 2 taps on iOS (maybe android too). It’s very frustrating. The first tap (click) does nothing, we have to tap a second time for the link to work.

This issue happens only when I add AdSense advertising. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the issue of links requiring two taps when integrating AdSense:

- Check for JavaScript conflicts.
- Use asynchronous AdSense loading.
- Review ad placement/layout.
- Test on various devices/browsers.
- Ensure up-to-date AdSense code.
- Disable ad blockers/extensions.
- Comply with AdSense policies.
- Contact AdSense support if needed.
- Consider user experience in ad placement.